# Why sizes attribute in img tag as we can use media query with image container instead?

Tags: css, responsive-images

OK this is the case : we want to display image in 50% of view port when viewport size is 800px or more otherwise image is 100% so the html look like the following:-

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="image.jpg" srcset="image.jpg 500px" sizes="(min-width:800px) 50vw,100vw" />
</div>
```

OR we can simply do the following through css:-

```
.container img{
   min-width:100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width:800px){
  .container{width:50%}
}
```

So we can control image container instead of image itself, my question here is is there is a condition that sizes attribute is  considered as the best solution ?

Notice:- I know that in the first example image size will be calculated based on the view port width and not the container width

Answer (score 0):

If you really only have one image resource, then you can do this with CSS only. `srcset`+`sizes` is only necessary if you want to let the browser choose which image file to download from a set of multiple files with different sizes. In that case, basing on viewport with in `sizes` is the only option (because browsers start to download images before external CSS has been downloaded, so container size is unknown).